# Can I create array by for loop in Kolin? the array is list listOfNames is inside a for loop but I can not use it outside the for loop

Tags: arrays, kotlin, for-loop, arraylist

Can I create array by for loop in Kolin? the array is the list [listOfNames] is inside a for loop but I can not use it outside the for loop. I have to get strings from Excel in to array list and use it in main method.

```
fun readFromExcelFile(filepath: String): ArrayList<String> {

        var listOfNames = ArrayList<String>()

        val inputStream = FileInputStream(filepath)
        var xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)

        val rowNumber = 0
        val columnNumber = 0
        val xlWs = xlWb.getSheetAt(0)
        for (i in 0..10) {
            var currentCell = xlWs.getRow(i).getCell(columnNumber)
            //println(currentCell)
            listOfNames.add(currentCell.stringCellValue)
            println(listOfNames)
        }
        //println(listOfNames)
        return listOfNames
    }
```

Comment: That's not creating an array; it's creating an ArrayList (which is a particular type of List that just happens to use an array in its implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you return a `List` instead of an `ArrayList` and populate a `MutableList` in your function:

```
fun readFromExcelFile(filepath: String): List<String> {
        var names = mutableListOf<String>()
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(filepath)
        var xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        val rowNumber = 0   // you don't use this.  
        val columnNumber = 0
        val xlWs = xlWb.getSheetAt(0)
        for (i in 0..10) {  // why isn't the range over the # of rows in the worksheet?
            var currentCell = xlWs.getRow(i).getCell(columnNumber)
            names.add(currentCell.stringCellValue)
        }
        return names
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it gave me a .NullPointerException, it doesn't print listOfNames outside a for loop, but thank you very much. I will try to change it somehow and use mutableList

Comment: What was null?   Fire up a debugger and fix it.  How do you know that there are 10 rows?  The loop range is fixed.  Bad idea.  How do you know that the name is always in column 0?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at base.test.MainKtKt.readFromExcelFile(MainKt.kt:29) //        var currentCell = xlWs.getRow(i).getCell(columnNumber)

 at base.test.MainKtKt.main(MainKt.kt:40)  //readFromExcelFile(filepath)

Comment: I made up just 10 rows in 0 columns. I tried debugger but after couple runs I am still not sure, how to fix it.

Comment: One pass through the debugger should tell you what the problem is.  It's either xlWs, getRow(i), or getCell(columnNumber).  One of those is null.